# Homework: HowTo obtain multiple keys collection?

Tags: .net, linq, collections

I have

```
public class Letter
{
    public string Value;
    public int Id;

    public Letter(string val, int id)
    {
        this.Value = val;
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

I need a kind of duplicate dictionary (`LookUp`(?)) for:

```
private something TestCollection()
{
    List<Letter> inputList = new List<Letter> { 
        new Letter("a", 9), 
        new Letter("b", 5), 
        new Letter("c", 8), 
        new Letter("aIdentic", 9) 
    };

    // compare inputList by letter's ID(!)
    // use inputList (zero based) INDEXES as values

    // return something, like LookUp: { "a"=>(0, 3), "b"=>(1), "c"=>(2) };

}
```

using .NET 4

**How to obtain it?**

As I understand, there is 2 solutions, one from .NET 4, `Lookup<Letter, int>`, other, classic one `Dictionary<Letter, List<int>>`

thanks.

EDIT:

For output. There is 2 letters "a", identified by ID 9 on index "0" in the array(first position). "b" have index 1 (second position in the input array), "c" - index 2 (is third).

## EDIT 2

John solution:

```
    public class Letter
    {
        public string Value;
        public int Id;

        public Letter(string val, int id)
        {
            this.Value = val;
            this.Id = id;
        }
    }

    private void btnCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Letter> inputList = new List<Letter> { 
            new Letter("a", 9), 
            new Letter("b", 5), 
            new Letter("c", 8), 
            new Letter("aIdentic", 9) 
        };

        var lookup = inputList.Select((value, index) =>
            new { value, index }).ToLookup(x => x.value, x => x.index);

        // outputSomething { "a"=>(0, 3), "b"=>(1), "c"=>(2) };
        foreach (var item in lookup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Output (I expect no more than **3** keys):

```
//WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter,System.Int32]
//WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter,System.Int32]
//WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter,System.Int32]
//WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1+Letter,System.Int32]
```

## EDIT 3 Equals

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Letter)
        return this.Id.Equals((obj as Letter).Id);
    else
        return base.Equals(obj);
}

public override int  GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your last example i.e. a dictionary of dictionaries? Did you try it? It sounds like you need multiple values per key, not multiple keys per value as the question suggests.

Comment: @chibacity: yes. There are multiple keys in the dictionary, so to each key corresponds an array of values.

Comment: @serhio A dictionary of lists is a good solution then. A single key can refer to a list with multiple items in.

Comment: @chibacity: maybe. The question is how to obtain it :)

Comment: @serhio I'm afraid 'obtain it' is not entirely clear. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: You've *nearly* copied my code, but not quite enough. `x => x.value` should be `x => x.value.Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lookup` is probably the right class to use here - and LINQ lets you build one with [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx). Note that `Lookup` was introduced in .NET 3.5, not .NET 4.

Having said that, it's not at all clear how you'd go from your input to your sample output...

EDIT: Okay, now that I understand you're after the index, you might want to use the overload of Select which includes an index first:

```
var lookup = inputList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                      .ToLookup(x => x.value.Id, x => x.index);
```

Comment: i know that such a function exist, however don't know exactly how to apply in my case. A litte example would be cool.

Comment: @serhio: Well, your example is far from clear - I can't see how you'd get from your sample input to your sample output - but I suspect that `inputList.ToLookup(x => x.Id, x => x.Value)` is what you're after. I strongly suggest that you take a few hours to read a LINQ tutorial though - it's not a great topic to pick up in this sort of way.

Comment: @serhio: Ah, by index. So the value is irrelevant? That would have been useful to make clearer... will edit my answer.

Comment: @serhio: See my edit for a suggestion. But should the "aIdentic" be "a" in your question?

Comment: yes. "a" == "aIdentic" See the output. I expect 3 keys, not 4 as we have, concretly the following LetterWithId=9, LetterWithId=5 and LetterWithId=8

Comment: @serhio: In what way is "a" == "aIdentic"? They're completely different strings. Was it a typo in the question, or did you forget to tell us how to compare IDs?

Comment: @Jon. Say I have x=Letter("a", 10) and y=Letter("a", 11). then x != y. Say I have x=Letter("something", 14) and y=Letter("Something", 14), then x == y. *if Ids are the same, two instances should be considered as the same key*. So, Letter("abc", 1) == Letter("xyz", 1), because the Ids 1 == 1

Comment: @serhio: Ah, I've got it - I hadn't read that the 9 is the ID, not the "a". With you now. I'm used to IDs usually being expressed *before* values... and for "Letter" I'd expected a textual ID. Having said that, my answer is still appropriate - your sample code uses `x => x.value`, not `x => x.value.Id` like mine does.

Comment: "Letter" is just a class name. it does represent a "Foo" for this example.

Comment: @serhio: "Foo" would actually have been clearer, to be honest - it wouldn't have suggested as strong a correlation between the textual part and its ID. (I hope your real code doesn't use public fields, mind you...)

Comment: @Jon, I agree, that Foo would be more clear :) this works. thanks! No real code does not use public fields :))

Comment: @serhio: Because the result isn't a `Lookup<Letter, int>` - it's a `Lookup<int, int>`. Your ID is of type `int`, not `Letter`. If you want to be able to look up by `Letter`, you can get rid of the ".ID" and implement `IEquatable<Letter>` in `Letter` itself (or just override Equals and GetHashCode).

Comment: Just last thing. Why does `Lookup<Letter, int> mLookup = (lookup as Lookup<Letter, int>);` return null? I need "letters"=>"idexes", not "letter Ids" => "indexes"... ok. ok. understood.

Comment: @serhio: `IEquatable<Letter>` *will* help, if you implement it properly - but that includes overriding GetHashCode.

Comment: equals + GetHashCode Worked :) I wrote the code in the Edit 3

Comment: @serhio: Your Equals implementation is far from ideal. There are lots of other questions on SO about how to implement it though - I suggest you do a bit of research on the topic.